# How to install SystemTimer on 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I've just upgraded my app from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 using RVM and had to add RubyGems and Bundler, ran bundle install and got everything to work except SystemTimer. Google-fu returns nothing and I see others have had issue with it in 1.9 but some have gotten it to work. Any ideas?

```
pawel:bodb pawel$ sudo gem install SystemTimer
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:48: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing SystemTimer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.3.0
-I/Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.
-D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers
-Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o system_timer_native.o -c system_timer_native.c
In file included from system_timer_native.c:8:
/Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_first_timer_and_save_original_configuration’:
system_timer_native.c:46: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:53: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:57: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:62: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:65: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:69: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:82: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:89: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:96: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:101: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_next_timer’:
system_timer_native.c:112: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:119: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:123: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:130: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:136: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:143: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:146: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_configuration’:
system_timer_native.c:157: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:160: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:168: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:170: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:172: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_timer_interval’:
system_timer_native.c:190: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:192: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_sigalrm_mask’:
system_timer_native.c:199: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:201: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_ruby_sigalrm_handler’:
system_timer_native.c:211: error: ‘rb_thread_critical’ undeclared (first use in this function)
system_timer_native.c:211: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
system_timer_native.c:211: error: for each function it appears in.)
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_ruby_sigalrm_handler’:
system_timer_native.c:217: error: ‘rb_thread_critical’ undeclared (first use in this function)
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘clear_pending_sigalrm_for_ruby_threads’:
system_timer_native.c:266: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c: In function ‘set_itimerval’:
system_timer_native.c:290: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
system_timer_native.c:295: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
system_timer_native.c:299: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [system_timer_native.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/SystemTimer-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/SystemTimer-1.2.3/ext/system_timer/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As far as I know, SystemTimer isn't relevant for ruby 1.9 and shouldn't use with this version.

"Using this gem in Ruby 1.9 is useless and does not make any sense! System Timer is trying to work around some limitation of the "green thread" model used in Ruby 1.8 (MRI). See http://ph7spot.com/musings/system-timer for more details."

Comment: Okay, so what should be used in Ruby 1.9 instead of `SystemTimer.timeout_after`?

Comment: Okay, see it.  `require 'timeout'; Timeout::timeout(5) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

A drop-in replacement for `SystemTimer` is `timeout.rb` from Ruby core. No need for any 3rd party gems.

Ruby 1.8:

```
require 'system_timer'

SystemTimer.timeout_after(5.minutes, MyException) do
  # your job here
end
```

Ruby 1.9:

```
require 'timeout'

Timeout.timeout(5.minutes, MyException) do
  # your job here
end
```

Answer (score -3):

To install system timer use this command in Terminal:

```
sudo gem install system_timer
```

Comment: You don't want to be using sudo with RVM.

Comment: This also won't help since system_timer won't be able to work with Ruby 1.8.7